# Error when using active x button to copy and paste

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I am trying to set up a command button that will copy and paste data from one sheet to another.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data").Activate

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data AC").Range("A1:J1000").Select
Selection.Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A2:J1001").Select
Selction.Paste


End Sub
```

I keep getting an error saying 'select method of range class failed', but cannot work out how to fix it.
Thanks

Comment: Don't use the clipboard for a simple copy action, the clipboard is a user resource that must be preserved. **Hint**: take a look at `Range().Copy()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Raw Data").Activate

Sheets("Data AC").Range("A1:J1000").Copy Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A2:J1001")


End Sub
```